# Calculate group functions (count, min, max...) for a column value without grouping

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

Let's say I have a following table:

Table users (id, name, age, city)

```
1 John    26 New York
2 Aaron   31 Dallas
3 Jenifer 35 Dallas
4 Connely 34 New York
```

And I'd like to have a table with all users with a minimum user age of his(her) city:

```
1 John    26 New York 26
2 Aaron   31 Dallas   31
3 Jenifer 35 Dallas   31
4 Connely 34 New York 26
```

This example is a bit artificial but I did not figure out any better *short* example.

If I'd use request like:

SELECT * FROM users MIN(age) GROUP BY city

I will probably get:

```
1 John    26 New York
2 Aaron   31 Dallas
```

I'm not sure that it will return rows 1 and 2 but that's not a point: I need to have **all** users in the result.

Is it possible?

Comment: Your question is written very complicated. What do you really want? You say: 1. I want the youngest User of each City // but you also say: 2. I want all Users // This looks like two different queries for me

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would be inclined to do this with a `join`:

```
select u.*, c.minage
from users u join
     (select city, min(age) as minage
      from users
      group by city
     ) c
     on u.city = c.city;
```

Comment: Yea this is good. I would use LEFT JOIN or LEFT OUTER JOIN to be explicit with "JOIN" though.

Comment: @Calvintwr . . . A `left join` is unnecessary because all the cities in the aggregation are in the table (and if `city` were `NULL` a `left join` would not quite do what you want).  If you want to be explicit, then you could write `inner join`.

Answer (score 1):

And I would do a sub-select:

```
select u.*, (select MIN(age) from users s where s.city = u.city)
from users u;
```